# What SMTP header allows me to control the MFROM address used in MTAs?

Tags: email, smtp

I need to send out an email with a custom Reply-To header and has a particular value for MFROM.  (the message envelope)

I have the choice to send though IIS SMTP, or Microsoft Exchange Server, and both of them relay through a managed service.

```
  IIS  -------|
              |---- Hosted Provider --- INTERNET ---Salesforce (who requires a specific MFROM)
  Exchange ---|
```

My goal is to make the MFROM (message envelope) appear as I require (for Salesforce compatibility).

**Question**

- How can I use Exchange or Microsoft IIS in this configuration to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

(everything below applies to Exchange 2010.  You didn't specify a version...)

There are a few ways to accomplish this, and none of them prevent your hosted provider from rewriting the headers as they see fit.

At your Exchange server from the EMC you can set the reply to address to anything you like (in 2010, Mailbox properties -> E-Mail Addresses -> uncheck "Automatically update...policy" -> Add envelopesender@whatever.com -> Set As Reply)

OR

If you have an Exchange Edge Transport you can accomplish this with Address Rewrite entries.  AFAIK address rewriting is not available on Hub Transport servers.

[This technet article describes the syntax creating address rewrites.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123966.aspx)

OR

You can set a [custom transport](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998315%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx) rule from the EMS.

All of this is astonishingly cumbersome from Exchange, btw.

Comment: Where do you get the terminology MFROM from, btw?  "envelope sender" is what I usually hear.

Comment: I've seen MFROM in various RFCs, email related document.  I've also heard P1 address refer to this, and P2 refer to the message body FROM.  Does this other naming jive with what you've heard?

Comment: Ah, it's from the Sender ID/SPF rfcs.  I'm old.